# Using jPicker in an EJS table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ejs, jpicker

I am trying to add a jPicker inside my table `<td>`. I create the table using EJS in this way:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><%= setting[i].name %></td>
        <td><span style="background-color: red" class="Alpha"></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the last `td` I add the `span` for the color picker. The code for jPicker is this:

```
$('.Alpha').jPicker({
    window: {
        expandable: true
    }
});
```

Why is this not working inside the EJS table? I just checked it in a regular table and it's working.

Comment: How many elements do you have with the id of `Alpha`?

Comment: i have 5 more element

Comment: There's your problem. `id` attributes must be unique. Change them to classes instead

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i edit the qustion . by changing the id to class. but still its not working

Answer (score 0):

If no `.Alpha` elements are being matched, this is probably because none exist yet when that code is running.

Make sure your `$('.Alpha').jPicker()` code comes **after** the table in your ejs file, or that you're wrapping inside `$(document).ready()` or similar to make sure it waits for the DOM to finish being written before trying to match elements in it e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.Alpha').jPicker({
        window: {
            expandable: true
        }
    });
});
```